# Why doesn't React update the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why doesn't React update the DOM for the following code? I'm expecting the highlighted item to change when the state changes, but this doesn't happen.

https://gist.github.com/davorb/abf505bac4f3f67f30bffffc539abf0a

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';

const food = [
  {
    key: 'Sushi'
  },
  {
    active: true,
    key: 'Burgare'
  },
  {
    key: 'Pizza'
  },
  {
    key: 'Pasta'
  }
];

const FoodList = (props) => {
  console.log(props.selected === food[0].key);
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={food}
        renderItem={({item}) =>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text
                      style={item.key === props.selected ? styles.activeItem : styles.textItem}>
                      {item.key}
              </Text>
            </View>}
        />
    )
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.i = 0;
    this.state = {
      selected: food[this.i]
    };

    setInterval(() => {
      this.i = (this.i + 1) % food.length;
      this.setState(previousState => {
        return {
          selected: food[this.i]
        };
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  renderFoodlist() {
    return (
        <FoodList selected={this.state.selected.key} />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
        {this.renderFoodlist()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 22,
  },
  textItem: {
    fontSize: 24,
  },
  activeItem: {
    fontSize: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get an infinite loop because of the setInterval(), did you notice that?

Comment: You should place the setInterval inside a componentDidMount() lifecycle method.

Comment: at the `previousState` please check that part.

Comment: The variable `i` you set on the component is really unnecessary.  You should set the state with the element index instead of the actual value in the array, since you are using static data. `setState(previousState => ({ selected: (previousState.selected + 1) % food.length }))`. In fact, what I would do is receive that `food` variable as props so I would not have to use global variables.

Comment: I've implemented the changes you guys requested [here](https://gist.github.com/davorb/77e3d7f4bb3aa3d5809c4359b134d401), but the problem hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html:

> By passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList we make sure FlatList
>   itself will re-render when the state.selected changes. Without setting
>   this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items
>   because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not
>   show any changes.

See this example and notice what happens when you comment out `extraData` (it won't update).

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';

const food = [
  {
    key: 'Sushi'
  },
  {
    key: 'Burgare'
  },
  {
    key: 'Pizza'
  },
  {
    key: 'Pasta'
  }
];

class FoodList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: 0,
    };
  }

  _renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({ selected: item.index })}>
        <View>
          <Text style={this.state.selected === item.index ? styles.activeItem : styles.textItem}>
            {item.index} {item.item.key}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={food}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
          renderItem={(item) => this._renderItem(item)}
          extraData={this.state}  // IMPORTANT!
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FoodList />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 22,
  },
  textItem: {
    fontSize: 24,
  },
  activeItem: {
    fontSize: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});
```